# Delivery data from parent to child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

After googling for hours and trying all king examples I still can't figure out how to call to a function that located in a child or pass any data to a child from the parent. I tried so many examples without success and i got really confused with the Vue, is it so complicated to pass a data to a child? Here is what I came up with from one of the examples but it does not work with me, maybe I do something wrong here? Thanks :(

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
   export default {
         name:'parent'
         data:{
             retrun:{
                  dataTochild:''
             }
         },
         methods:{
             callToChild:function(){
                 this.dataTochild = 'Hello Child'
             }
         }
   }
</template>

<child :myprop="dataTochild" />
<input @click="this.callToChild" />
```

**child.vue**

```
<template>
export default {
   name:'child',
   props:['myprop'],
   watch:{ 
     myprop:function(){
      alert('Hello Parent')
     }
   }
}
<template>
```

By the way, I am using Vue 2 version!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a spelling error on `return` (`retrun`), and there could be other errors on code you have omitted.

#### Working live demo

Here it is working on a [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l27lq2jj09)

#### Code

Parent

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <child :myprop="dataTochild" />
    <button @click="callToChild">Press me!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child.vue";

export default {
  name: "Parent",
  data() {
    return {
      dataTochild: "",
      counter: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    callToChild: function() {
      this.counter = this.counter + 1;
      this.dataTochild = "Hello Child " + this.counter;
    }
  },
  components: {
    Child
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Child

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <p>{{ myprop }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["myprop"],
  watch: {
    myprop: function() {
      console.log("Hello Parent");
      alert("Hello Parent");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
div.child {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, Marco for your help, yes it's working and I found the problem. In my code i have a button <button @click="setIndex(1)">Set Index 1</button> and when i remove "(1)" <button @click="setIndex">Set Index 1</button> it does work. I wonder now, how i can pass a var in to a function from a button click....

Comment: @Vadim you can pass a value, in general @click="myfunc(...)" is valid syntax (as also for other event handlers). Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in the console but what I did find out is when I pass a value as a string, like this @click="callToChild('0')" it working!!!!!  But when i pass as int value @click="callToChild(0) "it does not work.

Comment: strange, it should work with numerical values. In fact I've added an example to the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l27lq2jj09) and it works there too...

Comment: Yes I did the same test with your example and both values are working, I am not sure why on my end it reacts so differently to a different value type. Anyway, thanks for your help, I will try to find out later why it reacts so strange and will post here, for now, my components are working and communicating with each other so this problem was solved!!!